# Как работает этот цикл FOR в Python?

Tags: python

Не могу разобраться почему выходит такой результат, кто-нибудь коротко поясните:

```
rows = range(1, 4)
cols = range(1, 3)

for row in rows:
    for col in cols:
        print(row, col)

>>> 1 1
>>> 1 2
>>> 2 1
>>> 2 2
>>> 3 1
>>> 3 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Итератор `rows` генерирует по требованию три элемента - `1, 2, 3`, итератор `cols` - два элемента - `1 и 2`:

```
>>> range(1,4)
[1, 2, 3]

>>> range(1,3)
[ 1, 2]
```

Цикл `for` работает так: сначала для каждого `rows` пробегаются все значения `cols`, т.е. для `1` из `rows` все значения `cols` - 1 и 2:

```
>>> 1 1
>>> 1 2
```

потом для следующего элемента  из `rows` - двойки - все значения `cols`:

```
>>> 2 1
>>> 2 2
```

и так далее.

Более подробно читайте [тут](http://younglinux.info/python/for.php).

Comment: rows - не список, ваш ответ не про ту версию питона

Comment: @andreymal, благодарю за замечание, исправила

Answer (score 0):

При каждом фиксированном значении `row` значение переменной `col` во внутреннем цикле принимает значения из диапазона `[1, 3)`

Answer (score 0):

```
rows = range(1, 4)

# Конструкцию for можно применить к любому объекту(rows), имеющему атрибут __iter__
print(rows.__iter__)  # <method-wrapper '__iter__' of range object at 0x032C1770>

# У объекта вызывается rows.__iter__(), который возвратит объект, имеющий атрибут __next__
irs = rows.__iter__()
print(irs)  # <range_iterator object at 0x032C17E8>
print(irs.__next__)  # <method-wrapper '__next__' of range_iterator object at 0x02DA17E8>

# На каждом этапе итерации цикла for, у объект-iterator будет вызван .__next__(),
# который будет возвращять элементы rows-объекта, результат записывается в переменную(row)
print(irs.__next__())  # 1

# при достижении конца rows-объекта, .__next__() вернет raise StopIteration
# произойдет выход из for (StopIteration для циклов тоже самое что и break)
print(irs.__next__())  # 2
print(irs.__next__())  # 3
try:
    print(irs.__next__())  # выдавать уже нечего
except StopIteration:
    print('значения закончились')

# примерно так и работает цикл for
for row in rows:
    print(row)
```